# Remove YAML header from markdown file

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, yaml

How to remove a YAML header like this one from a text file in Ruby:

```
---
date: 2013-02-02 11:22:33
title: "Some Title"
Foo: Bar
...

---
```

(The YAML is surrounded by three dashes (-))

I tried

```
text.gsub(/---(.*)---/, '') # text is the variable which contains the full text of the file
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution, regex should be:

```
/---(.|\n)*---/
```

Answer (score 14):

The solution mentioned above will match from the first occurrence of `---` to the last occurrence of `---` and everything in between. That means if `---` appears later on in your file you'll strip out not only the header, but some of the rest of the content.

This regex will only remove the yaml header:

```
/\A---(.|\n)*?---/
```

The `\A` ensures that it starts matching against the very first instance of `---` and the `?` makes the `*` be non-greedy, which makes it stop matching at the second instance of `---`.